# What does the エセ in エセ感動 mean?

Tags: meaning, slang

Two characters are playing a game and talking about some more serious stuff at the same time. They both think the game is kinda crappy, and in particular they get to a scene that's trying to be emotional, but they feel it's just trying too hard/poorly done. However, one character then thinks:

> そんな、エセ感動シーンの力を借りて、今だけ、ちょっと真面目モードに移行する。

From what I can tell, this seems to be saying: Drawing power from the (crappy?) scene, he moves into serious mode.

However, I'm not sure exactly what エセ means. I suspect it's some slang.

Comment: See [似非](https://kotobank.jp/jeword/%E4%BC%BC%E9%9D%9E).

Comment: Woops. I forgot to check えせ because of it was written in katakana >.>

Comment: @istrasci: Do you know whether the two words are etymologically related?

Comment: @jogloran:  Which, エセ and ニセ from snailboat's answer?

Comment: Right, that's what I meant: sorry.

Comment: @jogloran Not likely, according to [this page](http://gogen-allguide.com/e/ese.html).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Japanese has a couple prefixes that are kind of like 'pseudo-' or 'fake'.

1. エセ- means it's fake because it isn't good enough to be the real thing.  For example, imagine a 'scientist' who takes  themselves seriously but you regard as a crackpot, not doing real science.  They could be an エセ科学者.
2. ニセ- (or 偽{にせ}-) means it's fake because it's really something else, but it looks like the real thing on the surface.  For example, if someone tries to sell you diamonds, but what they're really selling you are diamond-shaped pieces of glass, you could call those 偽ダイヤ.

In your example, they're saying it's a pseudo-emotional scene, in the sense that it's not good enough to qualify as the real thing.